# Android Livedata Room. Which method to use

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

In my Android Kotlin App. User profile (A form) needs to be updated using data from RestAPI eg. education and location data from API looks like this

```
{"educations": [{"edu_uid": 123, "edu_sector": "xxxx", "edu_degree": "xxx"}, .....}
{"locations": [{"loc_uid": 123, "loc_place": "xxxx", "loc_zip": "xxx"}, .....}
```

After consuming this data. We show it in an adapter. User choose his choice. We update XML views like @id/textViewEduSector and @id/textViewEduDegree. After filling up the form, When the User submit data I send only "edu_uid" "loc_uid" to the Server. Here is representation of my implementation:

```
profile_fragment -> education_fragment -> education_adapter onEducationClick -> 
navigateUp() -> profile_fragment update @id/textViewEduSector and @id/textViewEduDegree.
```

Then location and so. At the end when User submit the form,how can I pick "edu_uid" and "loc_uid" to sendback data to API endponit eg. "/profile/update".
How can I collect these uids temporarily. I have a Room database with all User fields. Here I donot want to retain hidden fields, "edu_uid" or "loc_uid". Is it necessary to update Room via Dao and then picking data from there and sent to API or any other workaround.? Fast and efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is hard to get the point of your problem, i try to give my general thoughts about your use-case.

Try to separate next issues:

1. What is [single source of truth](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#truth) in your app? Is it a local database? If not - why?
2. How to represent you data sources in UI?
3. How to synchronise your data structures with server?

**Data structures**. Try to use a database (ROOM) as a [single source of truth](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#truth) in your app. If you do, you get additional benefits of working without access to Rest API. In this case your ROOM-entities set should include - Education (edu_uid as Primary Key), Location (loc_uid as Primary Key) and User/UserProfile (with edu_uid and loc_uid as Foreign keys). In this case you should't add fields "edu_sector" or "edu_degree" to UserProfile data class. And with a action "submit" you have to save changes to your local database (with edu_id and loc_uid) and to solve your "REST API-question" at next step.

**Representation in UI**. If you use MVVM, you should't have a problems with "edu_id" or "loc_id". You declare references to Education and Location in your ViewModel and in your XML you can easy consume any fields of these objects.

**Sync with server**. It should be easy if you have efficient local database with all needed fields as foreign keys (again in your DAO you can get all the rest fields you want from other tables with table joins)

Again, maybe I didn't get your real problem. It is really unclear

Comment: Thanks sergiy for you help. that single source of truth article is really helpful. You judged my problem accurately. I was really enquiring. Is any other method there, to catch particular chosen fields (hidden from user) from RestData temporarily and letting the User to do his job. And while submitting make use of the catched data to submit to the Rest server. And the response only saved to Dao.

Comment: In your Representation in UI para; Are you suggesting putting an extra hidden TextView there to update data and then-consume-it-later kind of idea? I think this will make an extra view there. thats heavy for the thread. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Anyway I choose this method. User choose his choice -> we update Dao and finally we take fields from Dao, Send to server and again update Dao with incoming response. Is that better?

Comment: Can you explain that Represention in UI part little deeper. I am using MVVM. I think I need to hold data until final submission thats it.

Comment: As for representation in UI. What i meant. If in your ViewModel you hold reference to your Education or Location objects (with help of LiveData or in other observable-way), in your UI-TextViews you cold show just that fields that you need (without hidden ones). By using [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) for example. On the "Submit" button you can get your ID-things from the same Education/Location objects that you put in your ViewModel.

Comment: You are telling me I can bind "loc_place" and "loc_uid" to a single View, while showing up only "loc_place". And can later use both, right? Unfortunately after reading the docs I couldnt find it. Could you show me how is it for this particular example.

Comment: Well, I can only try to guess your flow. 1. In ProfileFragment you have a button "Choice location". 2. User press the button and you show fragment with locations list. 3. User choose and click the right location. 4. You get chosen location (selected Location object) and return it to ProfileFragment. 5. Returned Location object you set as a observable field in ProfileViewModel. 6. Field "loc_place" you should bind to TextView in UI with DataBinding. 7. User press "Submit" button and you get the loc_id field from your Location object in ViewModel and save it (and other fields) to database.

Comment: all your guessing is 100% perfect. I will get back to you after some other fixes, thanks so much

Comment: I did that in this way, can you look into my implementation and the issue. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508187/parcelable-model-reinstatiates-mvvm-room-livedata) as a seperate question